Air Conditioner Capacitor Ratings
I am changing capacitors in my 20 yo air conditioner. I looking to find out if I replace a 40+5UF capacitor with a 40+5 MFD?

MF or uF are the same

... mostly because megafarads would be flat-out terrifying...

They're the same
The Greek letter mu (μ) doesn't appear on most folks' keyboards, so back in the typewriter era, "microfarad" was sometimes abbreviated to "MFD", and that designation has stuck around in some areas.  More modern practice prefers "uF" if you can't type a μ, but they're all the same thing.  (A 1 megafarad capacitor would be vastly impractical for almost every application where a capacitor could conceivably be useful.)
